# Linq query conversion from C# To VB:NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I need help for convert a Linq Query. I've tried with on-line the conversion tools but no luck...
The query is this:

```
var orderedData =(from d in collezione
              group d by d.Gruppo into g
              orderby g.Key
              from d in g
 select new[] {d}.Union(g.Where(c => c.Owner == d.Comp)) into withChildren
                          from wc in withChildren
                          orderby wc.Pos
                          select wc).Distinct();
```

Comment: There are C# to VB.NET converters on the internet that can give you a big head start on a lot of this stuff...

Comment: OK, so you've told us the query and that you need help.  Neither of those things are questions. **What's the question?** What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: The biggest problem is the line with the select...

Comment: Does the original c# code work as expected? Because otherwise it would not be a conversion problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need(it's a random shot since your question is not complete):

```
Dim orderedData = From d In collezione
                  Order By d.Gruppo
                  Group d By d.Gruppo Into g = Group
                  From d In g
                  Select New With {
                      .withChildren = {d}.
                          Union(g.Where(Function(c) c.Owner = d.Comp))
                  }
Dim result = (From od In orderedData
              From wc In od.withChildren
              Order By wc.Pos
              Select wc).Distinct
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay. Yes the original code works fine.